# Create docker image for AWS Java Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, build.gradle, spring-cloud

We have created Lambda function using SpringCloud Function and created Jar

Now we want to create a Docker image using different base images.

Can someone suggest a way to do this?

below are code for spring handlers:

```
public class ExportCompressorEventHandler
        extends SpringBootRequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, String> {}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ExportCompressorEventFunction implements Function<Map<String, Object>, String> {}
```

Comment: why do you need docker?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html
just use the maven shade plugin on the lambda method and upload the jar...

full example: https://www.baeldung.com/java-aws-lambda

Comment: We are using the library for generating excel files. It is not working on the Coretta11 version.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example container-packaged Lambda function implementation on GitHub at [sigpwned/example-java-17-lambda-function](https://github.com/sigpwned/example-java-17-lambda-function) that uses [the community Java 17 lambda base image](https://gallery.ecr.aws/m6n4d7c2/sigpwned/aws-lambda-java-base-image).

There isn't enough information in the question to provide a complete answer for how to package your particular code as a lambda container, but if you look at the pom.xml and Dockerfile in that repository, you should be able to get your lambda function up and running.

If you add more detail to your question, I might be able to provide a more detailed answer.

Disclaimer: I created the Java 17 lambda base image and example lambda functions.